# Django Country/City dynamic selection : how to allow field value out of queryset in Modelfield?

Tags: django, django-models, autocomplete, dry

I am experiencing a problem with Django, trying to build a very simple (shame on me...) thing : I want to filter a ForeignKey ModelField, using another SelectField (with Ajax, for example : A "Country" selectbox autocompletes a "City" selectbox so the user can select his city).

My models look like :

```
class Country(models.Model):
    ...

class Town(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    ...

class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    town = models.ForeignKey(Town, related_name='persons')
    ...
```

Right.

Now I want a form to create/update a person, allowing the user to set a city in a selectbox **filtered by the value of another selectbox** (Country).

Here is the form I created :

```
class LazyChoiceField(forms.ChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, required=True, widget=None, label=None,
                 initial=None, help_text=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LazyChoiceField, self).__init__(required=required, widget=widget, 
                                              label=label, initial=initial, 
                                              help_text=help_text, *args, **kwargs)
    def valid_value(self, value):
        return True

class PersonForm(ModelForm):
    country = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all())
    town = LazyChoiceField(choices=[('0', "Chose a country firts!")])

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = ('user', 'town', )
        widgets = {
            'country': forms.Select(attrs={'onchange':'get_towns();'}),
        }
```

It works (providing a ajax.py file, serving a get_towns() function called via Ajax by Jquery script + a bit of JS stuff on the template page). But I am not really satisfied with this way of doing: excluding town field and adding another town LazyChoiceField doesn't seem DRY, does it?

My question is: is it possible to tell Django to not generate a validation error on a ModelField when the value selected is not in the initial queryset (actually, I can't render thousands of towns on the form !).

This feature (selecting Country/town) is very popular on the Web, but I didn't manage to find a simple Django snippet to do such a thing. What do you think about the solution I'm trying to develop? **How to do this better and following the DRY principle?**

If I don't exclude town from the ModelForm, my 30000 town selectbox makes the page really slow (and unusable)!

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: OK, I wrote to fast... Just found out django-smart-selects which is as simple as powerfull and allowed me to get the DRY touch !

Answer (score 0):

Glad you solved your issue. Just in case anyone else happens by, Django builds validation for selects against the `choices` passed in during instantiation. If you're going to do AJAX filtering of selects, your `choices` as far as Django is concerned must be every allowable choice, unfiltered. Use javascript to make the choices whatever you like after the page is rendered.

Comment: Hum, thank you very much for your answer, Chris. But what I would like to understand is how, in this case, could we deal with a 30000 values set ? If they are all `choices`, they will be pushed to the template and slow it down, even if we hide them with JS ?

Comment: That is a tough one. You can take some optimization steps potentially, by not querying for the full records (using `only`, `values` or `values_list` on the queryset). As far as the template goes, there's nothing saying you have to actually render them there. You won't be able to use any of the default `form.as_...` methods, though.